# array.filter not returning nested array of parent array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a nested array. I'm using `array.filter` to get the sub array from the parent array.

I have my data like this:

```
"accounts": [
    {

        "ID": "001yQdmAAE",
        "email": "inhome.user@ator.com",
        "users": [
            {
                "Name": "Inhome User",                    
                "MobilePhone": "34877"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "00mAAE",
        "email": "in.user@ator.com",
        "users": [
            {
                "Name": "Inhome r",                    
                "MobilePhone": "300077"
            }
        ]
   }]
```

I want to get users array from accounts array based on ID. I tried `array.filter`. It returns

```
    { "ID": "001yQdmAAE",
      "email": "inhome.user@ator.com",
      "users": [
        {
           "Name": "Inhome User",                    
           "MobilePhone": "34877"
        }
    }
```

I want only users array

```
const res=this.state.data.filter((res)=>{
 if(res.ID==record.ID){
       return res.users;
 }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: There's no `AccountID` property on the objects in your array? Did you mean to filter by `ID` maybe?

Comment: Sorry altered my actual code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite how [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works. `filter`'s callback function should return a boolean result which determines whether the element passed into the callback should be included in the return value of `filter`. After performing the filtration, we'll [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each result object to extract its `users` property.

```js
const /*this.state.*/data = {"accounts": [{"ID": "001yQdmAAE","email": "inhome.user@ator.com","users": [{"Name": "Inhome User","MobilePhone": "34877"}]},{"ID": "00mAAE","email": "in.user@ator.com","users": [{"Name": "Inhome r","MobilePhone": "300077"}]}]};

const targetID = "00mAAE";
const result = data.accounts
  .filter(e => e.ID === targetID)
  .map(e => e.users);

console.log(result);
```

But if `ID`s are unique, then use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter`, which locates only the first match:

```js
const data = {"accounts": [{"ID": "001yQdmAAE","email": "inhome.user@ator.com","users": [{"Name": "Inhome User","MobilePhone": "34877"}]},{"ID": "00mAAE","email": "in.user@ator.com","users": [{"Name": "Inhome r","MobilePhone": "300077"}]}]};

const targetID = "00mAAE";
const result = data.accounts.find(e => e.ID === targetID);

if (result) {
  console.log(result.users);
}
```

Comment: Find will return an array where filter().map() will return 2 dimensional array, maybe use filter().map().flat()?

Comment: If we have multiple results, then OP may want each one in its own subarray, but if not, yeah, `flatMap` or `flat()` or `[].concat(...res)` will work, depending on availability.

Comment: Rewording suggestion: "filter should return a boolean result" to "The filter callback should return a boolean result".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to also use `map` to return correct parts of the data:

```
const res = this.state.data.filter(res => res.ID === record.ID).map(item = > item.users); // Add map here to get users array
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter returns true or false, if it returns false then that element is filtered out.

You should filter first returning true or false and then use map to get only the users, maybe then use flat to convert the 2 dimensional array to a normal array.

```
const res=this.state.data.filter(
  res=>
    //return true or false in filter
    res.AccountID==record.AccountID
).map(
  //only need the users property
  res=>res.users
).flat();//flatten [users] to users
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {"accounts": [
    {

        "ID": "001yQdmAAE",
        "email": "inhome.user@ator.com",
        "users": [
            {
                "Name": "Inhome User",                    
                "MobilePhone": "34877"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "00mAAE",
        "email": "in.user@ator.com",
        "users": [
            {
                "Name": "Inhome r",                    
                "MobilePhone": "300077"
            }
        ]
   }]
}

function getUsers(){
    var xx;
    data.accounts.forEach(x => {
        if(x.ID == "00mAAE"){
            xx = x.users;
        }
    })
    return xx;
};

console.log(getUsers());
```